# Getting MYSQL value from dropdown box

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So I have some php code to return a mysql table to a dropdown box, as follows:

```
$hostname = ""; //SET SERVER/HOSTNAME
$dbusername = ""; //SET DATABASE USERNAME
$dbname = ""; //SET DATABASE NAME
$dbpassword = ""; //SET DATABASE USERNAME
$link = mysqli_connect($hostname, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname); 

if (!$link)
{ 
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') ' . mysqli_connect_error()); 
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM utility ORDER BY program_code"; 

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) 
{    
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        $selectbox.='<option value=\"' . $row['program_code'] . '\">' 
        . $row['program_code'] . ' - ' . $row['rate'] . ' - ' . $row['term'] . '</option>';
    }

    $selectbox.='</select>';

    mysqli_free_result($result);

    echo $selectbox;
}
```

That works fine, then I just call that into my form. My problem is when an option is selected, I need to get and return that value so I can pass it on to whatever else I am doing with the values from my form. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select name="select">
  <option value="foo">foo</option>
</select>
```

PHP:

```
$select = $_POST["select"];
echo $select; //Should return foo
```